# UrlFetchApp with proxy

Tags: google-apps-script

What about several requests per second simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL Fetch calls go through Google's servers. So:

1. If you mean using a proxy to ask Google to fetch a URL, then yes.
2. If you mean asking Google to fetch a URL through a proxy server, then no.

Also, from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) on Quotas for Google Services, you cap at 20,000 calls/day.